# How can one use HashiCorp Vault in Airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, hashicorp-vault

I am starting to use Apache Airflow and I am wondering how to effectively make it use secrets and passwords stored in Vault. Unfortunately, search does not return meaningful answers beyond a [yet-to-be-implemented hook in Airflow](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3669) project itself.

I can always use Python's `hvac` module to generically access Vault from `PythonOperator` but I was wondering if there is any *better* way or a *good practice* (e.g. maybe an Airflow plugin I missed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Airflow >=1.10.10** supports Secrets Backends and supports getting Airflow Variables and Connections from Hashicorp Vault.

More Details in Airflow Docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/use-alternative-secrets-backend.html#hashicorp-vault-secrets-backend

If you want to test it locally check the tutorial at https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-and-hashicorp-vault/

Set the following config in `airflow.cfg`, update based on your environment:

```
backend = airflow.contrib.secrets.hashicorp_vault.VaultBackend
backend_kwargs = {"connections_path": "connections", "variables_path": "variables", "mount_point": "airflow", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8200"}
```

Example DAG to test the integration:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook


def get_secrets(**kwargs):
    conn = BaseHook.get_connection(kwargs['my_conn_id'])
    print(f"Password: {conn.password}, Login: {conn.login}, URI: {conn.get_uri()}, Host: {conn.host}")

with DAG('example_secrets_dags', start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:


    test_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='test-task',
        python_callable=get_secrets,
        op_kwargs={'my_conn_id': 'smtp_default'},
    )
```

Comment: Is it possible to renew vault token programmatically from the hook or operator ?

Comment: @leftjoin Trying to figure this out as well

Comment: No, it is currently not possible to renew vault token natively.

Comment: same here. our tokens expire every 12 hours. the closest thing i got regarding renew is this:
1. install the `vault` command line tool within my airflow docker image
2. set `backend_kwargs = {..., "token_path": "/usr/local/airflow/.vault-token", ...}` in `airflow.cfg`
3. ask a leprechaun to go into each airflow container and do `$ vault token renew` every 6 hours since i'm told by the internet that setting up a cron job in the docker container is difficult and not recommended

Comment: Does anybody know whether I can actually use a **path** to the connection? For instance, specify the top hierarchy as `connections_path`: `backend_kwargs = {"connections_path": "kv"}` and then when calling the `PythonOperator` in the example above, use a path as `op_kwargs={'my_conn_id': '/my_secrets/dev/smtp_default'}` so that the connection inferred from Vault would then be `kv/my_secrets/dev/smtp_default`?

Comment: No you can't, you will have to set: `{"connections_path": "kv/my_secrets/dev/"}`

Comment: I would say for all except a very dedicated vault secret mount (which may or may not be available to your company), the integration is severely lacking. It imposes it's own structure, and that (in our case, and I suspect others), made it more or less worthless

Comment: airflow cannot read secret values from vault if i set `variables_path` to other than `variables`? any idea how i can read values from other paths than `variables`

this doesn't work `"variables_path": "my_custom_variables"`

Answer (score 1):

Additional things to keep eye on If you are new to Vault:

Validate that your airflow.cfg backend_kwargs parameter mount_point really exists in vault:
`vault secrets list`

Try your DAG code above with command line first before trying it in web interface 
`airflow test example_secrets_dags test-task 2020-06-04`

Answer (score 0):

How to config with SSL vault
backend = airflow.contrib.secrets.hashicorp_vault.VaultBackend
backend_kwargs = {"connections_path": "connections", "variables_path": "variables", "mount_point": "airflow", "url": "https://127.0.0.1:8200"}