# Vault with airflow on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, vault

I installed **vault** as a separate service with kubernetes as auth. I installed minikube and installed airflow on it. I enabled apache-airflow kubernetes as well.
Once I start airflow with kubernetes, I want to connect it to vault using **airflow secret backend and kwargs** using **kubernetes auth type**.
How to get the vault token returned from kubernetes secret login from airflow?

Please suggest any way or any example to achieve this.

Comment: I think there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61670806/11977760) you're looking for in another stackoverflow question. Could you please take a look and let me know if that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you @Jakub for your reply. its some what different. I am able to access vault locally with airflow using same method as mentioned in the above link. However, in my case, I have vault with kubernetes setup. Now i want to have kuernetes with airflow and use kubernetes auth method instead of default token in airflow kwargs which eventually will return vault token.

Comment: which version of airflow you are using? can you mention please?